# BigDecimal is losing precision

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm using BigDecimal, and it lost precision when it print rate and add the rate.

```
import java.math.MathContext;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
public class Calc
{

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        MathContext mc = new java.math.MathContext( 3 );

        double r = 1668.00;
        BigDecimal rate =   new BigDecimal( r,mc );
        BigDecimal taxWitholdingRate = new BigDecimal( 0.1185, new MathContext(4) );
        BigDecimal unitFrequency = new BigDecimal( 11.5,mc);

        System.out.println(   rate  );
        System.out.println(   taxWitholdingRate  );
        System.out.println(   unitFrequency  );


        BigDecimal serviceCost2 = new BigDecimal(0,mc);
        serviceCost2 = rate.multiply(taxWitholdingRate, mc  );  
        System.out.println(   serviceCost2  );
        serviceCost2  = serviceCost2.add( rate, mc);                        
        System.out.println(   (BigDecimal)serviceCost2 );
        serviceCost2 = serviceCost2.multiply(unitFrequency );
        System.out.println(   serviceCost2 );
    }    
}
```

java -cp . Calc
1.67E+3
0.1185
11.5
198
1.87E+3
21505

Comment: You are using a scale of 4! Shouldn't you be expecting that?

Comment: `new MathContext(3)` constrains the precision to 3 *significant digits*, not *decimal places*. Decimal places are controlled by the `scale` property on the `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming these are supposed to be currency figures (to the hundredths), I think you wanted to use [`BigDecimal.setScale(int, RoundingMode)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29) and something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal rate = new BigDecimal("1668.00");
    BigDecimal taxWitholdingRate = new BigDecimal("0.1185");
    BigDecimal unitFrequency = new BigDecimal("11.5");

    System.out.println(rate);
    System.out.println(taxWitholdingRate);
    System.out.println(unitFrequency);

    BigDecimal serviceCost2 = new BigDecimal("0");
    serviceCost2 = rate.multiply(taxWitholdingRate);
    System.out.println(serviceCost2.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    serviceCost2 = serviceCost2.add(rate);
    System.out.println(serviceCost2.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    serviceCost2 = serviceCost2.multiply(unitFrequency);
    System.out.println(serviceCost2.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
}
```

Output is

```
1668.00
0.1185
11.5
197.66
1865.66
21455.07
```